# Make a variable accessible to all running programs

Tags: python, variables, integration, global

My messy solution:

I am a beginning python programmer and because of my lack of advanced knowledge, I often use primitive tools to finish my advanced projects. Currently I am trying to exchange data between programs at runtime. I have tried writing and reading text files. Each program has a separate write-only text file in order to avoid two programs writing to a file at the same time.

In order to collect all the data into a single file, I have written a separate program to read the write-only text files and consolidate all the data into a single file. All programs then have access to variables from all other programs in this one file.

My request for an easier solution:

Even though the above solution works well, I am trying to find a more elegant way to share variables among Python programs. Can you tell me if there is a better way to do this in Python?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you considered a database?

Comment: but txt file is really better if variable is only one :) Or file based database - sqlite, h2

Comment: Why exactly would you want this?  If a set of programs all need the same information at runtime and need to talk to each other, why are they not classes/functions in the same program?  Perhaps if you told us why you need this feature, we could give a more reasonable solution.

Comment: If you have two Python programs and you want them to interact, you don't need to add extra "data layers" between them. Just `import one` of them from the `other` and share the data directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is more or less designed for what you describe, since a *variable* is as volatile as memory.

[Redis](http://redis.io/) is another good option, with some similarities to memcached, but the option to make the data persistent.

All the other direct-sharing options I could think of fall directly into the category of *database* (whether SQL or not), except for using flat files, which is what you're doing now.

Finally, you could refactor the programs so that instead of sharing values directly, they provide services to one another whereby they can trade information when they need it. This may increase overhead and complexity in some cases, but eliminates the need to validate the cache of variable values if they ever change.

Comment: Thanks I will find out more about these modules. Redis seems to be cool, i think it will save a lot of my time :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) to communicate between the programs. However, if the data you're sharing is always relevant to all programs then, as others have suggested, a central database would be a better fit.

Alternatively, if all the programs are written in Python, you could launch them all from the same interpreter on different [threads](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=thread#thread-objects). Threads share the same memory space so sharing variables between them is already built-in (just make sure to read/write them in a thread-safe way).